# C# - Add Separator to TreeView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, treeview

How can I go about adding a separator in between treeview nodes?  uTorrent manages to do this but I can't find any documentation.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use [Owner Draw](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.drawnode.aspx) to achieve the same effect.